# Что такое node.js, react.js и тд?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js

Все привет, я **начинающий** фронтенд разработчик. Было бы интересно узнать что такое node.js, react.js, vue.js(если правильно написал) и тд. И как они относяться к JavaScript , так же зачем они нужны?(с примерами). *Зарание спасибо!*

Comment: node.js — платформа для запуска javascript-кода. react.js и vue.js — библиотеки, написанные на javascript

Comment: Если вы не знаете, зачем они вам нужны — значит они вам не нужны. Никто не запрещает делать фронтенд без вот этого вот всего (хотя это нынче уже не модно)

Comment: node.js - https://nodejs.org/en/about/

Comment: react.js - https://ru.reactjs.org/

Comment: vue.js - https://ru.vuejs.org/index.html

Comment: Нет бы на ютьюбе поискать...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так-с, начнём.

Node.js - javascript фреймворк, работающий на стороне Вашего ПК(что-то типа python с синтаксисом js). Для фронтенда используется как автоматический сборщик для других фреймворков(vue.js, react.js, sass), но также не один а с пакетами типа webpack, gulp, vite (очень рекомендую vite).

Vue.js - javascript фреймворк для, непосредственно, фронтенда. Максимизирует возможности языка javascript для фронтенд разработки. Попробовав его, Вы будете вспоминать то, что делали до этого момента как страшный сон)

React.js - также js фреймворк для фронтенда. Не могу сказать, чем он отличается от Vue и прочих.

Для правильной разработки это всё очень хорошие вещи(совмещать vue и react в одном проекте не надо, выберите что-то одно). Могу уверить, что Вам понравятся)

От себя могу порекомендовать использовать Vue + Sass + Vite для хорошего фронтенда. Подробнее Вы можете узнать в очень хорошей документации к vue https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html Гайды на ютубе смотреть не рекомендую, лучше изучайте документацию. Также vue предоставляет шаблон, в котором Вы сможете покопаться и разобраться, как всё устроено. Постарайтесь не бросить программирование, если Вы что-то не понимаете. А продолжайте кропотливо искать информацию в гугл. Также не рекомендую постоянно писать вопросы на стэковерфлоу, ведь тогда Вы не станете хорошим программистом и не сможете нормально программировать, ожидая ответа на Ваш вопрос. Enjoy!

Comment: Спасибо большое за столь полезный и развернутый ответ! Учту все советы. А на счет стаковерфлоу, я пишу вопросы не часто, просто решил раз и навсегда разобраться с этими страшными названиями.

Comment: React.js не фреймворк, а библиотека.